# Ruby on Rails: Why empty value is displayed when form for creation of new objects in DB is included?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am newbie. I am trying to develop a simple web application involving shops and candies where a shop can have many candies.

I have the following code in my shops/show.html.erb which displays list of candies twice.

```html
<% i=0 %>
<% for candy in @shop.candies do %>
    <% i+=1 %>
    <%= i %> <%= candy.name  %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for([@shop, @shop.candies.build]) do |f| %>
            <%= render(:partial => 'form',
                       :locals => {:f => f, :header => "Add a Candy", 
                       :placeholder => "Enter a candy name"}) %>
<% end %>

<% i=0 %>
<% for candy in @shop.candies do %>
    <% i+=1 %>
    <%= i %> <%= candy.name  %>
<% end %>
```

My code in _form.html.erb for creating a new candy:

```html
<%= f.text_field(:name, :placeholder=> placeholder, :class=>"form-control custom-input")%>
<%= button_tag( :class => "btn btn-primary mb-2 btn-custom btn-custom-sc") do %>
      <i class="fas fa-plus icon"></i>
<% end %>
```

Code of Shops Controller:

```html
class ShopsController < ApplicationController

def show
       @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
       @unshelved_candies = @shop.candies.unshelved_candies
    end
    private
        def shop_params
          params.require(:shop).permit(:name)
        end

end
```

Code of Candies Controller:

```html
class CandiesController < ApplicationController

   def create
      @shop = Shop.find(params[:shop_id])
      @candy = @shop.candies.create(candy_params)
      redirect_to(shop_path(@shop))
    end

    private

            def candy_params
              params.require(:candy).permit(:name)
            end   
   end

end
```

When I run the code and view it on browser, I notice that it creates an empty candy in the second loop (not in database). However, when I remove the form for creating candies, it behaves as it should. I am unable to understand why it's looping one more time and displaying blank value.
The output of the first loop is the correct one:

1. Candy 1
2. Candy 2
3. Candy 3

And the output of second loop is:

1. Candy 1
2. Candy 2
3. Candy 3
4. [<---Empty. I am not inserting anything new to the database]

Can anybody tell me why it is displaying a blank value in second loop and how to prevent this extra iteration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the "extra" candy is the one you're instantiating here:

```
<%= form_for([@shop, @shop.candies.build]) do |f| %>
```

The candy name for the new candy is nil, so you're getting the blank.

BTW, this:

```
<% i=0 %>
<% for candy in @shop.candies do %>
  <% i+=1 %>
  <%= i %> <%= candy.name  %>
<% end %>
```

Strikes me as non-idiomatic ruby. I would expect to see something more like:

```
<% @shop.candies.each.with_index(1) do |candy, index| %>
  <%= index %> <%= candy.name  %>
<% end %>
```

I guess a brute force way of making sure you don't get that extra candy would be to do something like:

```
<% @shop.candies.each.with_index(1) do |candy, index| %>
  <% unless candy.new_record? %>
    <%= index %> <%= candy.name  %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You might also try:

```
<%= form_for([@shop, @candy]) do |f| %>
```

Which I believe can be written:

```
<%= form_for(@shop, @candy) do |f| %>
```

If you want to save yourself a couple of key strokes (they add up over time).

And then in your `ShopsController` do:

```
class ShopsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
    @candy = Candy.new
    @unshelved_candies = @shop.candies.unshelved_candies
  end

  private

  def shop_params
    params.require(:shop).permit(:name)
  end

end
```

This is also nice because it avoids:

```
@shop.candies.build
```

Which requires that your `view` knows a lot about the relationship between `shop` and `candies` and also requires that your `view` interacts directly with the database.

Since you're apparently using nested routes, you might want to look at the [shallow: true](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting) directive.

Also (this is not related to your question), you *might* want to be thoughtful about the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter#In_object-oriented_programming). I notice you do:

```
@unshelved_candies = @shop.candies.unshelved_candies
```

Personally, I would do something more like:

```
@unshelved_candies = @shop.unshelved_candies
```

And in `Shop`, you might have something like:

```
class Shop < ApplicationRecord

  def unselved_candies
    candies.unshelved
  end

end
```

And in `Candy`, something like:

```
class Candy < ApplicationRecord

  class < self 

      def unshelved
        where(shelved: false) # or however you determine a candy is unshelved
      end

  end

end
```

Many people would make `unshelved` a `scope`, which is another way of doing the same thing.

This way, your `ShopsController` knows less about the mechanics of the relationships between shops and candies and shelved status. FWIW.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way I can modify the form so that the extra candy is not created?

Comment: Updated answer.